# Insertar múltiples registros con SQLite + Java

Tags: java, sqlite

Tengo la necesidad de insertar múltiples registros con SQLite desde Java de una sola vez. La cantidad podría llegar hasta 500 entradas.

Para intentar hacerlo tengo lo siguiente:

```
public void insertar(List<P> lista) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("insert into productos")
        .append("(col1, col2, col3, colN)")
        .append(" values ");
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        sql.append("(");
        sql.append(lista.get(i).getCol1()).append(", ");
        sql.append(lista.get(i).getCol2()).append(", ");
        sql.append(lista.get(i).getCol3()).append(", ");
        sql.append(lista.get(i).getColN()).append(") ");
        if (lista.size() - 1 != i) {
            sql.append(", ");
        }
    }
    CONNDB.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql.toString().getBytes());
    CONNDB.commit();
}
```

Éste código lanza un error SQLite:

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (unrecognized token: "091d50bf3d5049bca22d2ac41361fc69")

En donde "091d50bf3d5049bca22d2ac41361fc69" es uno de los valores correspondientes a *col1*.

Las preguntas que me surgen son:

¿Qué hago mal aquí? y si existe una manera mejor de realizar lo que necesito.

Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres irte a lo más simple podrías usar Room. Te facilitaría la vida como no tienes idea, no solo al insertar sino al mantenimiento y uso de la base de datos en general.

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, me lo guardo para el futuro, pero ahora no es lo que necesito.

Comment: Sugerencia. Prueba el código con un par de elementos e imprime el sql por consola, para ver si es una instrucción SQL bien formada. De hecho la puedes ejecutar en una consola SQL y afinar para ver qué es lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno lo primero daros las gracias a todos por las aportaciones y por el interés mostrado.

Al final se trataba de un problema con los valores pasados que insertaban una comilla donde no debía.

Bueno el resultado es este:

```
public void insertar(List<P> lista) throws SQLException {
    lista.stream.map((p) -> {
        String sql = "insert into productos (col1, col2, col3, colN) "
            + "values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement pstm = CONNDB.PreparedStatement(sql);
        pstm.setString(1, p.getCol1());
        pstm.setString(2, p.getCol2());
        pstm.setString(3, p.getCol3());
        pstm.setString(4, p.getColN());
        pstm.executeUpdate();
    });
    CONNDB.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como yo lo veo intentas introducir solo los valores de los productos. Supuestamente supongo que la "lista" solo contiene los valores.

Te daré mi solución que hice yo una vez con un simple `Array()` y me funciona a la perfección.

Donde *databaseSQL* es un *ArrayList(String)* y contiene líneas completas como:

```
INSERT INTO productos (col1, col2, col3, colN) VALUES (val1, val2, val3, valN);

INSERT INTO productos (col1, col2, col3, colN) VALUES (val1, val2, val3, valN);

...
```

---

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // **************************************
    // * Metode abreviat del execucio SQL   *
    // **************************************

    for (String dbSQL : dataBaseSQL) {
        db.execSQL(dbSQL);
    }

}
```

Solo con esto me funciona perfectamente la Base de Datos.

Para tu situación, yo haría:

```
public void insertar(List<P> lista) {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    for (P prod:lista) {
      sql.append("insert into productos")
        .append("(col1, col2, col3, colN)")
        .append(" values ");
        sql.append("(");
        sql.append(prod.getCol1()).append(", ");
        sql.append(prod.getCol2()).append(", ");
        sql.append(prod.getCol3()).append(", ");
        sql.append(prod.getColN()).append(");");
    }
    CONNDB.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql.toString().getBytes());
    CONNDB.commit();
```